# How to show new category products on home page?

Tags: category, theme, product-list, ce-1.8.1.0, home

I  have search but cant find anything than can help me understand how to make this possible 
i want to show the New products from each category on my home page 
I'm using Magento CE 1.8.1 and Fortis Template 
i'v managed to show the New product in my home page but cant seem to Get them split by categories
since i don't know so much of this ''coding'' stuff if possible i would appreciate some help

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3):

I think it should help you
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page

So, result added string should be something like that

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" category_id="ID OF SHOWING CATEGORY" name="home.catalog.product.new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

Comment: @ Denis Kopylov 
this solves my problem in part; i need to change the NEW.phtml so that the products are presented as my list.phtml
if you check my website you will see the diference 
[link]www.presentes-desejados.pt                                              i want my new products to show as the List.phtml show's

Comment: Yes, you should create new template like list.phtml or use template="catalog/product/list.phtml"

Comment: like this does not work
{{block type="catalog/product_new" category_id="4" name="home.catalog.product.new" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}